# setAllowedCapturePolicy not working for Samsung devices on Android Q and above

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

According to [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setAllowedCapturePolicy(int)),

```
mAudioManager.setAllowedCapturePolicy(AudioAttributes.ALLOW_CAPTURE_BY_NONE);
```

should block internal audio recording. In my testing, this works for the built-in system screen recording for Pixel devices, but not for Samsung devices. On Samsung devices, the internal audio can still be recorded despite setting `ALLOW_CAPTURE_BY_NONE`.

Has anyone encountered this and found a workaround?

Comment: Have you find any solutions? I am also having  a similar problem and couldn't find any workaround yet.